Minimap & flow creation missing
Title: Minimap and Flow Creation Unavailable in Dialogflow CX
Problem Description:
I'm experiencing an issue in Dialogflow CX where the minimap for flow control is not visible, and I'm unable to create new flows. This makes it difficult to manage and expand my agent's conversation structure.
Next Steps:
I'll review the provided troubleshooting tips and consider reporting a bug if the issue persists.
problem
Tried & Expected:
Opened Dialogflow CX console and navigated to an existing agent. Expected to see the minimap for flow control and the option to create a new flow. However, the minimap is missing, and creating new flows is unavailable. Tags: dialogflowcx, minimap, create flow, troubleshooting
